# Calling a Function in an Ethereum Contract from a Specific Multi-Signature Wallet

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to call a Function in an Ethereum Contract from a specfic Mist Multi-Signature Wallet. The function can only process commands from that wallet address. My computer is quite slow so installing Mist or similar tooling is not an option. MyCrypto wallet and MyEtherWallet do not have this functionality. Is there any browser based tool out there that will enable me to accomplish
this task? Alternatively, any HTML/JavaScript code, I can adapt to the job?

Answer (score 1):

Mist has not been maintained for 5 years or so now.

It's unlikely anyone on this forum, or any forum, can help you.

If you have funds stuck in Mist wallet, then hire a professional consultant to recover them.

Comment: I haven't got funds stuck in the Mist Wallet, I need to use the wallet to call a contract where the fund is.  I haven't used solidity for years now but I have used (way back) ethereum web API to write HTML/Javascript interfaces that will do what I need now. I assume the space has vastly improved. There has to be some simple ways to build an interface to do this without a steep learning curve.

Comment: The Myst Wallet is in essence a user interface.  There has to be some web3 tooling to interact with the early ethereum.org multi-sig contract. There are too many of it deployed in the wild

Comment: Most people moved away from Mist around 2016. It's unlikely anyone has been interested to maintain Mist tooling for many years now. You can still interact with it directly using its ABI files and Web3 libraries like Web3.py and Web3.js, but it's something you are likely going to figure out yourself, or hire a professional to do it for you. Your best bet is to read Mist source code and replicate its functionality in modern JavaScript.

Comment: Thank You Mikko.. I have given ChatGPT a task using HTML/Web3.js and the ABI's. It has produced the code, I have to test it. I will see how that goes. I should have given it the Mist source code as well :)